# How to remove a specific JSON object from a file?

Tags: command-line, json

I have the following JSON data in a file:

```json
{
  "packages": {
    "cc": {
      "name": "cc",
      "version": "3.1",
      "release": "0.4",
      "arch": "x86"
    },
    "code": {
      "name": "code",
      "version": "3.0",
      "release": "2.0.2",
      "arch": "x86"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove the whole `code` object from the file. How can I do that using a command-line tool?

Comment: Have a look at `jq` or similar tools.

Comment: @dirkt yes, had a look at ```jq``` . i can use it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete the `.packages.code` key and its value, using `jq`:

```bsh
jq 'del(.packages.code)' file.json
```

To delete any entry under `.packages` whose `.name` key has the value `code`:

```bsh
jq 'del(.packages[] | select(.name == "code"))' file.json
```

The same two commands, but they take the `code` string from a shell variable:

```bsh
string=code

jq --arg key "$string" 'del(.packages[$key])' file.json

jq --arg key "$string" 'del(.packages[] | select(.name == $key))' file.json
```

Redirect the output to a new file and replace the old file with that if it looks ok.